# How to set custom Web Part values through powershell?

Tags: web-part, powershell

I am using a powershell script to initialize several values of a custom webpart and then insert that webpart onto a page.  I have been partially successful using the method below:

```
$multiPartLeftWebPart = New-Object MultiPart.MultiPart.MultiPart
$multiPartLeftWebPart.CurveEquation = "{""x0"":5,""y0"":-11,""x1"":107,""y1"":-44,""x2"":257,""y2"":-56,""x3"":403,""y3"":-55}"
$multiPartLeftWebPart.SelectedTabs.Add("News")
$multiPartLeftWebPart.SelectedTabs.Add("FAQ")
$multiPartLeftWebPart.SelectedTabs.Add("Events")
```

In this webpart CurveEquation and SelectedTabs are custom values used by my webpart that are typically set through the editor pane.

My Issue is that when I go into my editor pane after I have run my script only the CurveEquation value is set.  CurveEquation is a string and SelectedTabs is a `List<string>` object.

I have stepped through my code when the editor part is loading and confirmed that CurveEquation has the expected value and that there are 0 items in Selected tabs.

Do I need to do something special to set values of a `List<string>` object using powershell in this way?

Code for the property:

```
    [Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared), WebBrowsable(false)]
    public List<String> SelectedTabs
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

Comment: In the public property of the webpart for SelectedTabs, do you have an XmlElement attribute defined?

Comment: No I don't, should I?

Comment: I've updated my question to show the code for the property that is not getting set.

Comment: Yeah, I' try with `[XmlElement(ElementName = "SelectedTabs")]` I'm wondering if the webpart isn't serializing properly.